# Have two conditions in a do while statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use two conditions in the `while` section of my `do ... while` statement.

The following code works:

```
do {
    var longitud = parseInt(prompt("increase longitude of array"));
} while (isNaN(longitud));
```

The following also works:

```
do {
    var longitud = parseInt(prompt("increase longitude of array"));
} while (longitud < 2);
```

However when I want to incorporate them both, it does not work:

```
do {
    var longitud = parseInt(prompt("increase longitude of array"));
} while (longitud < 2 && isNaN(longitud));
```

The problem is not the parentheses; I have tested all possible combinations and nothing happens.
So, how do I group both expresions in the same while?

Comment: What about putting the expressions in a variable?

Comment: is it (isNaN(longitud) || longitud < 2)? means if longitud is not valid or smaller than 2, continue for input

Comment: Define "nothing happens". First of all, maybe test to see if it's a number *first*, *then* check the numeric comparison.

Comment: Check your statement first, if that is actually what you even want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you actually want an "or" rather than "and"? (So replace `&&` with `||`).

It's not possible for longitude to be both less than 2, and not a number. So, you probably want to continue your loop when *either* is true.

You'll also want to reverse the two - as in, `isNaN(longitud) || longitud < 2`. If longitude is not a number, then you'll want to check that first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your problem is in your while statement. Nothing happens because the while statement will NEVER find longitud < 2 and isNAN at the same time.
Change to this and try:

```
do{
    var longitud = parseInt(prompt("ingrese longitud del array"));
}while(isNaN(longitud) || longitud < 2);
```

In your code, you were checking if longitude was both <2 AND isNAN. You want it to loop while longitude is less than 2 or isNAN.

Edited: Added Katanas answer, which explains it should check for isNAN first.